# Could not find the implementation for builder @angular-builders/jest:run

Tags: angular, npm, jestjs

I'm following the instruction from this article on howto use "Jest" with Angular `ng test`: https://codeburst.io/angular-6-ng-test-with-jest-in-3-minutes-b1fe5ed3417c

I see the same instructions in the README for the Jest Angular8 builder here: https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/jest

When I run `ng test` I get:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find the implementation for builder @angular-builders/jest:run
See "/tmp/ng-7Fpvvi/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Output from the error log is follows:

```
[error] Error: Could not find the implementation for builder @angular-builders/jest:run
    at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder (/home/dheater/src/taskbox/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js:49:19)
    at TestCommand.initialize (/home/dheater/src/taskbox/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:134:55)
    at async TestCommand.validateAndRun (/home/dheater/src/taskbox/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command.js:124:9)
    at async Object.runCommand (/home/dheater/src/taskbox/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:186:24)
    at async default_1 (/home/dheater/src/taskbox/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js:50:31)
```

Versions are:

```
+ jest@24.9.0
+ @angular-builders/jest@7.4.4
```

and I see the package in `node_modules/@angular_builders/jest`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Angular 8, update the verison for @angular-builders/jest as well.

Comment: I've since delete the project, but if someone can verify, I'd be happy to accept this answer.

Comment: I can verify it worked for me after upgrading the version of `@angular-builders/jest`: to `^9.0.0`,